# Swift inefficient table view model?

Tags: ios, performance, swift, syntax, model

My syntax here is probably a little inefficient, and my approach to sorting data for presentation in a table view might also need revision.

Any tips on improving efficiency here would be much appreciated. My table view model will be an instance of this class called 'session details'

```
class SessionDetails {

    // session -> registration -> person

    let session: Session
    private var _attendees: [Person]?
    var attendees: [Person] {
        get {
            if _attendees == nil {
            if let collection = self.session?.registrations {
                let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: true)
                if let registrations = collection.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sort]) as? [Registration] {
                    var collector = [Person]()
                    for registration in registrations {
                        if registration.person != nil {
                            collector.append(registration.person!)
                        }
                    }
                    _attendees = collector
                }
            }
            return _attendees!
        }
    }

    init(session: Session) {
        self.session = session
    }

    // rest of class truncated
```

EDIT: session, registrations and person are NSManagedObjects. A session has an NSSet of registrations. A registration has a one-to-one with Person.  So in other words, many people can register for a session.

Comment: I have added some optimization points in my answer. If you could elaborate more about the nature of Session, Registration and Person and how they are being used we may be able to suggest more and better optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you have only one init() method then there is no need of making session data member as optional. The init(session: Session) guarantees that session will always have a value.

If session.registrations are fixed and are not going to change then you should make attendees a lazy loading property. It will save you doing the sorting again and again when attendees property is accessed.

```
class SessionDetails {

    let session: Session
    private var _attendees: [Person]?

    var attendees: [Person] {
        if _attendees == nil {
            //No optional binding i.e. 'if let' required as the initializer is not failing one.
            let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: true)

            //No optional binding i.e. 'if let' required as session is not optional. 
            //sortedArrayUsingDescriptors() method never returns nil.
            //Also we are sure returned array is of type [Registration] so no need to put as? operator.
            let registrations = session.registration.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sort]) as [Registration]

            var collector = [Person]()
            for registration in registrations {
                if let person = registration.person {
                    collector.append(person)
                }
            }
            _attendees = collector
        }
        return _attendees!
    }

    init(session: Session) {
        self.session = session
    }
}
```

Made it a bit more streamlined and removed some if let conditions that were not required.

Comment: Hi abdullah. Good point about the optional. However, in regards to lazy loading, I explicitly want to re-compute the sort because the database may update.

Comment: In case of database change you may put some flag that indicates there was a change in data and only then you compute the sort. If database changes are not very frequent this may save you quite a lot of processing and in most cases it will have O(1) running time.

Comment: For the time being, I have put a private ivar in the getter, and whenever I update the database, I will set the ivar to nil, so the sort gets refreshed.  But this doesn't feel right.

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you did. Could you please modify the question with new code to show what exactly you did.